# Couchbase 4010 Error

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I've been testing Couchbase 5 and created a bucket called `fp-conversion-data` which has some JSON data in it. I have been trying to run some simple queries such as:

```
SELECT * FROM fp-conversion-data limit 5;
```

Instead of getting the expected results, I keep getting this error:

```
[
  {
    "code": 4010,
    "msg": "FROM expression term must have a name or alias",
    "query_from_user": "SELECT * FROM fp-conversion-data limit 5;"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have dashes in the name of the bucket. Use backticks (`) around the bucket name.

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `fp-conversion-data`
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Sh*%! That did it! Might be good to update that you need to use ` and not ' which is what I had tried previously.